# What is wrong there? textarea shows nothing but value is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing code to show hints to the user in `<textarea/>` in grey color;

Idea is next:

1. Initially place `'Please, type your inquiry there'` in grey color;
2. If user clicks on it, color changes to black and text to `''`. This part works fine;
3. If user types and then deletes (i.e. leave field blank) than we need to put `'Please, type your inquiry there'` in grey color back in.

Step (3) does not work in Chrome nor in Firefox. It displays nothing. When I use Chrome inspector, it shows:

> element.style { color: rgb(141, 141, 141); }

which is right, and `"Please, type your inquiry there"` in HTML, which is also right. But the field is empty. What might be the problem???
I specifically used `console.log()` and they also display output that should be...

This is the HTML and JS code:

```
<textarea name='contact_text'  id='contact_text'  
                        onclick='text_area_text_cl();' onBlur='text_area_text_fill();'> 
                </textarea>

<script>
    var contact_text_changed = false;
    var contact_contacts_changed = false;
    
    function text_area_text()
    { 

            if (contact_text_changed == false)
            {
                $("#contact_text").css("color","#8d8d8d");
                $("#contact_text").html('Please, type your inquiry there');
            }
            else
            {
                $("#contact_text").css("color","#000000");
            }
            // Write your code here       
    };
    function text_area_text_cl()
    {
        if (contact_text_changed == false)
        {
            $("#contact_text").text('');
            $("#contact_text").css("color","#000000");
            console.log('sdfdfs111');
            contact_text_changed = true;
        }
    };
    function text_area_text_fill()
    {
        if ($("#contact_text").val() == '')
        {
            contact_text_changed = false;
            $("#contact_text").css("color","#8d8d8d");
            $("#contact_text").html('Please, type your inquiry there');
            //document.getElementById('contact_text').innerHTML = 'Please, type your inquiry there'
            console.log('sdfdfs');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('__');
        }
    };
    // call functions to fill
    text_area_text();

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the value of a `<textarea>` you need to use `.val()`:

```
$("#contact_text").val('');
```

or

```
$("#contact_text").val('Please, type your enquiry there');
```

etc.  It's tricky to make "placeholder" code work properly. [Newer browsers allow](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder):

```
<textarea placeholder='Please, type your enquiry there' id='whatever'></textarea>
```

and they manage it all for you.

*edit* — from the comments, here's an explanation as to why it appears that `.html()` works (well, it *does* work, but read on) initially.  The markup contents of a `<textarea>` element — that is, the DOM structure contained within the element — represents the *initial* value of the `<textarea>`.  Before any user interaction (and/or before the "value" property of the DOM has been touched by JavaScript), that's what's shown as the value of the field. Changing that part of the DOM, then, changes that initial value. Once there's been some user interaction, however, the initial value is no longer relevant to the page view, so it's not shown. Only the updated value is shown.

Comment: I agree with the answer but still wondering why the `html()` to set the value works initially and not when the `value === ''`.

Comment: @Harry I don't know that myself; looking into it

Comment: Same here, I will try and if I find anything I will let you know so that you can maybe add it to the answer :)

Comment: @Harry In Firefox, it seems that `.html()` works until there's been some user interaction with the `<textarea>`. After that point, it stops working.

Comment: @Harry ah, I think it's because the child text nodes of a `<textarea>` represent the **initial** value.  Thus, it's probably the case that `.html()` still "works" after the user's interacted, but the initial value has become irrelevant because user interaction has altered it.

Comment: Exactly the same behavior in Opera 15 too. So I guess WebKit and Gecko are following the same method. Your previous update seems to be the case. Let me see if I can find any documentation regarding that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I also was wondering what's wrong. By the way, text() give same result as html().

Comment: @Tigran and Pointy: Another thing I noticed is that if we use `.val()` the gray color is not applied (in Opera). Not sure about Firefox or IE.

Comment: It seems like if a `textarea` has value set by both `.val()` and `.html()`, the former always takes precedence. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/2nWL4/) we can see that the text area shows value as `abcd` when both lines are uncommented (even though `.html()` is executed after) but when we comment the `.val()` line, the value of `.html()` is shown.

Comment: Also, if we add a `console.log` of `$("#contact_text").html()` after the value is set in the original code, we can see that the value is there but it is just that it is not shown.

Comment: It is. As I wrote, it is in inspector also. It is just now shown. May be you can refresh whole DOM or redraw site (base on existing DOM). Do you know how to do it??? By the way, problem was solved, and now we are finding issue there =)